# Вычисление количества положительных, отрицательных элементов и нулей

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал всё, кроме вычисления количества положительных, отрицательных элементов и нулей. Проблема такова, что выводятся сами числа, а не их количество. Подскажите, где ошибка в коде. Готовые функции `sum` использовать нельзя.

сам код:

```
import random
res = [random.randrange(-2000, 5000) for i in range(10)]
print("рандомный списочек чисел: " + str(res))
max1 = res[0]
for ele in res:
    if ele > max1:
        max1 = ele
print("максимальное число: ", max1)
min1 = res[0]
for ele in res:
    if ele < min1:
        min1 = ele
print("минимальное число: ", min1)
i = 0
for i in res:
    if i > 0:
        i += 0
        print(i)
for j in res:
    if j < 0:
        j -= 0
        print(j)
for k in res:
    if k == 0:
```

Comment: i += 0  и что измениться?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде очень много ненужной фигни. Эта задача запросто решается с помощью встроенных функций  python.

Но, насколько я понял, Вы хотите решить задачу через циклы.

***ход решения***:

Во-первых, Вам не нужно три раза пробегаться циклом по списку, так как это займет больше времени. Все, что Вам нужно завести три переменных, а затем в одном цикле пройтись по элементам и смотреть: если число больше нуля, то к переменной, которая отвечает за количество положительных чисел прибавить единицу; если число меньше нуля, то прибавить единицу к переменной, отвечающей за количество отрицательных чисел; аналогичная ситуация и с числами, равными нулю.

*P.S. не люблю решать задачи обучения за кого-то, но думаю, что этого хватит, чтобы решить задачу.*

Comment: спасибо большое за направление и совет, сделал только что так, да всё заработало, насчёт функций знаю, что с помощью них легче и быстрее можно сделать, но пока что нельзя их использовать, поэтому цель была сделать всё самому